# Can't change part of an array in SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel

I am trying to Paste with adding value to cell containing SUMPRODUCT, but it says "You can't change a part of an array". The only special with the `SUMPRODUCT` is that it is conditionally summing from multiple sum ranges (3 sum columns): `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A6=A10),B2:B6+C2:C6+D2:D6)`:
[image]
The problem occurs when I try to Paste with adding value from another cell this this `SUMPRODUCT` cell:
[image]

Anyone, please help. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, @JosWoolley. I usually do paste value with adding with other formula (```SUMIFS```, ```VLOOKUP```, etc.) but not to this modified SUMPRODUCT, just wondering... 


The adding values are from other floating formula cells. Pasting value is the best way to fixed it. I have to do this to many cell , that is why.


If this modified ```SUMPRODUCT``` cannot help, I have to do repeated multiple ```VLOOKUP``` or ```SUMIFS```

Comment: Apologies, you are correct. I will have to look into this a bit more.